# SystemJS package config path map for subdirectory

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm struggling with mapping path for systemjs.

Below is my current configuration.
I want `@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect` to be
`@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect/index.js`

but it keeps directing to 
`@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect.js`

I'm assuming I'm not writing correct map or I should be using meta instead...
Could someone walk me through?

```js
'use strict';
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function () {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '../node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      "@angular-redux/form": "npm:@angular-redux/form"
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      '@angular-redux/form': {
        main: 'dist/source/index.js',
        map: {
          './connect': './connect/index.js',
          './connect-array': './connect-array/index.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are mapping to the correct location.

if you have

```
import '@angular-redux/form/dist/source/connect'
```

the mapping needs to be something akin to this:

```
'./dist/source/connect': './dist/source/connect/index.js',
'./dist/source/connect-array': './dist/source/connect-array/index.js'
```

if you have

```
import '@angular-redux/form/connect'
```

the mapping needs to be something akin to this:

```
'./connect': './dist/source/connect/index.js',
'./connect-array': './dist/source/connect-array/index.js'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks